# Create a virtual table s.t. list collaborators and the number of times two people collaborated

Tags: sqlite

Schema for table 1 (t1):

```
t1(projectid integer, score integer)
```

Schema for table 2 (t2):

```
t2(id integer, unique_id integer, string_name text)
```

id should refer to a projectid. score is intuitively a numerical ranking for projectid. unique_id is a numerical id for a person, string_name is the name of the person.

I'm looking to create a virtual table such that it has this schema:

```
cg(id1, id2, avg_score, count)
```

id1, id2 refer to the unique_id of t2 such that id1 and id2 have worked on 2 or more projects and the average score is bigger than or equal to N (some integer). count is the number of projects which id1 and id2 collaborated on.

So I've started with:

```
 CREATE VIEW cg as SELECT unique_id as id1, unique_id as id2, avg(score) 
 as avg_score, count(projectid) as mcount from t1, t2 WHERE id1 != id2 
 GROUP BY projectid HAVING count(projectid) >=2 and avg(score) >= N.
```

But this seems wrong. So a little help would be nice. For testing purposes, I'm letting N = 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just giving a column two names does not give you different values; you have to select them from two different instances of the table.
With the `GROUP BY projectid`, you get exactly one project per group.

Try this instead:

```
CREATE VIEW cg AS
SELECT p1.unique_id AS id1,
       p2.unique_id AS id2,
       AVG(prj1.score + prj2.score) / 2 AS avg_score,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM t2 AS p1
JOIN t2 AS p2 ON p1.id = p2.id AND
                 p1.unique_id < p2.unique_id
JOIN t1 AS prj1 ON p1.id = prj1.projectid
JOIN t1 AS prj2 ON p2.id = prj2.projectid
GROUP BY p1.unique_id,
         p2.unique_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
   AND AVG(prj1.score + prj2.score) / 2 >= N
```

Comment: I'm really confused by this code. If p1 and p2 are just aliases for t2, then haven't you just said t2.pid = p2.id AND t2.unique_id < p2.unique_id. The first part is trivial and the second part of the AND statement can't ever be true.

Comment: How are p1 and p2 supposed to be different instances of the table?

Comment: "Different instances" means that p1 and p2 can refer to different records of the same table.